# Upload multiple Iteration statuses into same Jira Xray ID with JUnit XML

Tags: junit, jira-xray

I'm attempting to upload the iteration statuses of an X-ray test case which has parameters from a Data Set. I'm using the Jenkins pipeline with the XrayImportBuilder plugin. Before uploading the XML file to Xray, I am able to update it. Would someone kindly explain how to add iteration results to XML so that XRAY can read it.

**Following is the Xray Test Case Iterations Section**
[image]

**Current JUNIT XML**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, currently is not possible using the JUnit XML format as there is no way to embed that information within the JUnit XML report.
You would need to use the [Xray JSON format](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Using+Xray+JSON+format+to+import+execution+results) instead.

If you're using the TestNG framework, there's an [open-source project](https://github.com/Xray-App/xray-testng-extensions) that provides a listener that can generate Xray JSON reports with support for data-driven "manual" (i.e., step-based) test cases.
If you're using other test automation frameworks, you may need to implement this (the generation of Xray JSON report) by yourself.